# SQL Server snapshots/backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am aware that SQL Server supports database-level snapshots, but is there a way to create a snapshot or backup of **the entire SQL Server instance?** (including all server-level logins, permissions, roles, objects, databases, etc.)

(For SQL Server 2012 and up)

Comment: What are you looking to do?  Clone a sql instance from one server to another?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I'd like to run a bunch of T-SQL against my instance, then restore the instance to its state as it existed *before* I ran the T-SQL.

Comment: Is your SQL Server instance on a virtual machine? If it is, you can take a VM snapshot, right? If it is not, I think @Vulcronos has the right idea (see his answer below).

Answer (score 0):

The master database stores the server level logins and other meta data.  If you back up this system database along with msdb and model, you will have all server level information backed up.

Outside of sql server you could take a VM or SAN snapshot to capture the entire server state.

Comment: I understand that not all metadata is stored in these system databases. Some things are stored in the system registry (max allowed error logs, etc.), so I'm not convinced that backing up master, model, and msdb is sufficient.